# Bash / Shell: Parsing CSV file in bash script and skipping first line

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I am trying to parse a csv file (that contains userIDs and working hours for each user).
I have written the following script:

```
#save weekly average to a file
    while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
    do
        echo "$col2  ($col3+$col4+$col5+$col6+$col7)/5"
    done < user-list.txt
```

I am facing the following two problems:

1. I want to skip the first line of the csv file since it contains the headers
2. I am trying to calculate the average value but the echo command does not execute the expression.

Some sample data from the input file is:

```
Computer ID,User ID,M,T,W,T,F
Computer1,User3,5,7,3,5,2
```

Any help would be appreciated. TIA

Comment: please update the question with a few sample lines from `user-list.txt` as well as a) the current (wrong) output generated by your script and b) the desired (correct) output you're looking for; also, are you looking for the average for each line or do you also need an average for the entire file (your sample/desired output should show answer this question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP hasn't (yet) provided any sample input data nor the desired output so some assumptions:

- data values could be integer or reals, positive or negative
- the user wants the average for each line (no need to calculate an average for the entire file)

Some sample data:

```
$ cat user-list.txt
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
1,id1,3,4,5,6,7
2,id2,13,14.233,15,16,17
3,id2,3.2,4.3,5.9233,6.0,7.32
4,id4,-3.2,4.3,-15.3,96.0,7.32
```

One `awk` solution:

```
$ awk -F"," 'FNR>=2 { printf "%s %10.3f\n", $2, ($3+$4+$5+$6+$7)/5.0 }' user-list.txt
```

Where:

- `-F","` - use comma as input field separator
- `FNR>=2` - skip the first line of the file
- `printf "%s %10.3f\n"` - print field 2 using `%s` format; print the average using `%10.3f` format (width of 10 w/ max of 6 digits to left of decimal plus the decimal plus 3 digits to the right of the decimal); append a linefeed (`\n`) on the end

The above generates:

```
id1      5.000
id2     15.047
id2      5.349
id4     17.824
```

---

OP has added a new requirement ... sort the output by the calculated averages however, there are a few potential issues that need further input from the OP:

- Can a userID show up more than once in the data file?
- If a userID can show up more than once then do we need to generate a single line of output for each unique userID or do we generate separate lines for each occurrence of a userID?
- Is the data to be sorted in ascending or descending order?

For now I'm going to assume:

- A userID may show up more than once in the source data (eg, as with `id2` in my sample data set - above).
- We will **not** combine multiple lines for a given userID (ie, each line will stand on its own).
- We'll show sorting in both ascending and descending order.

While the sorting can be done within `awk` I'm going to opt for piping the `awk` output to `sort` as this will require a bit less code and (imo) be a bit easier to understand.

**Ascending** sort:

```
$ awk -F"," 'FNR>=2 { printf "%s %10.3f\n", $2, ($3+$4+$5+$6+$7)/5.0 }' user-list.txt | sort -nk2
id1      5.000
id2      5.349
id2     15.047
id4     17.824
```

Where `sort -nk2` says to sort by column #2 using a `n`umeric sort.

**Descending** sort:

```
$ awk -F"," 'FNR>=2 { printf "%s %10.3f\n", $2, ($3+$4+$5+$6+$7)/5.0 }' user-list.txt | sort -rnk2
id4     17.824
id2     15.047
id2      5.349
id1      5.000
```

Where `sort -rnk2` says to sort by column #2 using a `n`umeric sort but to `r`everse the order

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! Is there anyway that I can sort the output based on the calculated average?

Comment: @SaadUrRehman updated to show some ideas for `sort`ing the data by calculated averages

Comment: I would like to get a little explanation on things, if you may. I am assuming `FNR>=2` is for skipping the first line. However, can you explain `printf "%s %10.3f\n", $2, ($3+$4+$5+$6+$7)/5.0` a little more?

Comment: scroll up in the answer; just after the first `awk`, see the paragraph that starts with `Where:` ... there are 3 bullets explaining the `awk` command; the same explanation/bullets apply to the follow-on `awk` commands

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
awk -F, 'NR > 1 { map[$2]=($3+$4+$5+$6+$7)/5 } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc";for (i in map) { printf "%s %.2f\n",i,map[i] } }' user-list.txt
```

Use comma as the field delimiter through -F, Add the third, fourth, fifth, sixth and seventh fields and divide by 5, putting the result in an array called map, indexed by the user ($2). Ignore the headers with NR > 1. At the end, set the sorting of the array to value number ascending and loop through the array, printing the index (user) and the value to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem this should solve the problem:

```
#save weekly average to a file
while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
do
    echo "$col2  ($col3+$col4+$col5+$col6+$col7)/5"
done < <tail -n +2 user-list.txt
```

The second is a bit more complex - the echo command is only used to display variable contents or output of ny kind, it is not for mathematic expressions. Use the `expr` command like this:

```
myvar=$((1 + 2)); result=$(($myvar / 3)); echo $result
```

Something like this, with a little adaption to your problem will solve it.

Comment: You say "use the `expr` command" but then you don't. (That's a good thing *per se;* don't use the `expr` command.) What you have is a Bash arithmetic expression, which basically replaces `expr` entirely.

Comment: This is what I wanted to do, but `< <tail -n +2 user-list.txt` doesn't work. Did you mean `<<< $(tail -n +2 csv.csv)`?

Comment: I think you want `done < <(tail -n +2 user-list.txt)`

Comment: This part `< <tail -n +2 user-list.txt` didnt work for me.